# How to create expandable FAQ page in HTML?

Tags: html, google-sites

I'd like to create an FAQ page for my website that lists all of the questions as hyperlinks.  When the link is clicked, the answer for that question should expand out beneath it.

The answers need to be hidden by default, and preferably clicking the link toggles the answers' visibility.

Any thoughts?

*Edit*

I've tried several of the suggestions, but unfortunately it looks like google sites doesn't allow any of that functionality in the html.  I can't use scripts, styles, embed, iframe, or anything beside basic text formatting it would appear.  Great ideas everyone, but it looks like I'll have to settle for a Table of Contents style FAQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple example using jQuery:

JavaScript/jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.faqlink').click(function(){
        $('.content').hide();
        $(this).next('.content').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.content {
    display: hidden;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<h2>My FAQ</h2>
<a class="faqlink" href="#">Link 1</a>
<div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
<a class="faqlink" href="#">Link 2</a>
<div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
<a class="faqlink" href="#">Link 3</a>
<div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: You don't really need the hide() part. You can just do this: $(this).next('.content').toggle(); and have the links toggle from hide and show and the display should be 'none' instead of 'hidden'.

Comment: What if one need to link to one of those links from an external page?

Comment: The 'href="#"' is useless and gave me some issues on my Phonegapp app. Without it the behavior is correct.

Answer (score 9):

Here a possible approach:

```
<html><body><script>

function toggleElement(id)
{
    if(document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none')
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
<p>
<a href="javascript:toggleElement('a1')">Is this a question?</a>
</p>
<div id="a1" style="display:none">
This is an answer.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, have the answers in a `div` container each below the question.

The divs will have `display:hidden` attribute by default.

Upon clicking on the links, this CSS style will be removed with JavaScript.

Something like this with Query (needs testing for typos etc.):

```
$(function()

  { $("a[name='Question1']").click(function()

    { $("div[name='Answer1']").removeClass("answer-hidden"); }); });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, google sites doesn't appear to support styles.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to study the code of "Expandable FAQ" - it is available on GitHub:
https://github.com/SolidMVC/ExpandableFAQ
And it's has that expand-collapse mechanizm avialable at /UI/Templates/Front/FAQsList.php
( https://github.com/SolidMVC/ExpandableFAQ/blob/master/UI/Templates/Front/FAQsList.php )

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML you use this pattern:

```
<div style="parentContainer">
  <div style="titleContainer" onclick="toggleContents(this)">Link to click on</div>
  <div style="contentContainer">Some content here.</div>
</div>
```

and in the Javascript toggling is simple:

```
function toggleContents(elm) {
  var contentContainer = elm.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];
  contentContainer.style.display = (contentContainer.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```