# Why doesn't the collapsible list work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The website for a company I'm thinking of signing up with has a bug regarding a collapsible list (https://www.servermule.com.au/vps-hosting/linux/). The FAQ at the end of the front page has one question with a visible answer and the rest with hidden answers - and you can't toggle back and forth between the two options by clicking on the title. I have brought up the html code in the developer tool that comes with Chrome and the relevant difference seems to be that the first question is set at 'collapse in' and the rest are set at 'collapse out'.

I have not coded html before but since the Chrome tool doesn't allow copy and paste I've tried to replicate the issue with simple html code snippets from various tutorial websites. None of them replicated the issue. Obviously I need to learn html, but for now what would be a simple code example to replicate this issue and correct it?

Comment: To the downvoter: I need an answer goddamnit! Why don't you try doing that?

Comment: when u click the title,there is an error! debug it

Comment: I'm considering a VPS because my chromebook is no good for any software development, and crouton repeatedly bugged me. But that obvious problem with the VPS companies' website disturbs me so I need to correct it first, which I can't do because I've only coded python so far.

Comment: Edit the code of your Page. See here for how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403146/how-to-create-expandable-faq-page-in-html

Comment: @SudiptaBiswas Thanks, p2u's answer worked so I've passed that on. I don't know about gu jefer's answer yet. I'll leave this post up because if someone searches it may match my wording. I didn't find your linked post in the initial search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change data-parent="#accordion1" to data-parent="accordion1"

Comment: Thanks, will try that...

Comment: It worked! Now they have to make the menu options collapsible again, maybe using Jake Taylor's technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203279/bootstrap-close-responsive-menu-on-click