# Google Site Collapsible List

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

I've found several resources that supposedly show one how to make a collapsible list in Google Sites, but nothing seems to work.  I've tried inserting an HTML box into the site, as well as modifying the HTML source code.  It seems like Google Sites is just stripping away any javascript.  Is there a way around this, does Google have a feature to make this happen (that is not the list template, that will not do for my purposes)?

Here are the resources I've tried:

tutorials.seowebpower.com/google-sites-advanced/collapsible-table

sites.cognitivescience.co/knowledgebase/resources/using-google-sites/creating-information-rich-gsites-pages

[How to create expandable FAQ page in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403146/how-to-create-expandable-faq-page-in-html)

support.google.com/sites/search?q=list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fiddled with one of the answers in the linked question and it seems to work for me now, giving two questions with hidden answers which toggle hide/show, you should be able to adjust that to be a folding list once the hide/show functionality is there.

This in an htmlbox

```
<script>
function toggleElement(myid)
{
    if(document.getElementById(myid).style.display == 'none')
    {
        document.getElementById(myid).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(myid).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

<hr>
<button id="q1">Is this question one?</button>

<div id="a1" style="display:none">
This is the first answer.
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('q1').onclick=function(event) {toggleElement("a1"); };
</script>

<hr>

<button id="q2">Is this question two?</button>

<div id="a2" style="display:none">
This is the second answer.
</div>
<script>
document.getElementById('q2').onclick=function(event) {toggleElement("a2"); };
</script>

<hr>
```

see it in action at

https://sites.google.com/site/dpcarlisle/fold

(first click takes forever for things to load up here, not sure if google sites allows enough javascript to preload things, but after first use it works as expected)

Comment: Thanks, David!  I should be able to work with this.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

- The documentation provided in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/ can help you.
- After creating a normal JavaScript collapsible list the code has to be pasted in the `Index.html` file.
- Once you have your `Code.gs` and `Index.html` files, publish the project: `Publish → Deploy as Web app`, and pick `«Anyone, even anonymous»`.
- Copy the `«Current web app URL:»` and embed it in your Google Sites page: `Insert → Apps Script`.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- YOUR JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```