# Expandable FAQ page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to create an expandable FAQ page. I referred to several threads on stackoverflow which had answers but when I implemented it in my code I couldn't get the expandable answers to questions on the page.

When I click on the question it shows no changes

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
</script>

<script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.faqlink').click(function(){
        $('.content').hide();
        $(this).parent('td').next('.content').show();
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.content {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="faqlink" href="#"><?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<h3><b>".$row["question"]." </b></h3>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        ?></a>
        <br><br>
        </td>
        <td class="content">
            <?php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<h3><b>".$row["answer"]." </b></h3>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        ?>
        <br><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3T5l.png)

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McQ0u.png)

Comment: The php code here is not useful.  Share your HTML instead.  And why are you using `style.display` when you are asking about JQuery which has `toggle` built in?

Comment: `document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';`

Comment: I referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403217/8974868 for the code

Comment: I updated my code in the question

Answer (score 0):

First, `display: hidden` isn't a thing. I think you're looking for `display:none`.

jQuery's `.next()` function only looks at siblings and your `.content` is not a sibling of `.faqlink`. You're instead looking for the sibling of `.faqlink`'s parent.

```
$(this).parent('td').next('.content').show();
```

This would be the naive way of handling it, but usually in cases like this, I prefer to use my loop that is rendering the content to set a unique ID for the content and refer to it that way. Makes the javascript more manageable and easier to read and makes the lookup faster.

Comment: Something else I just noticed, `display: hidden` isn't a thing. The property you're likely looking for is `display:none`. That is likely the problem, because everything else seems to be working fine.

https://codepen.io/bhylton/pen/bYvLxQ

Comment: It works if I don't use php to pull data from database...I want to extract questions and answers stored in the database

Comment: Can you update your question with the HTML that is output after the PHP has ran?

Comment: After clicking on the question the URL is appended with #